# Compare two Lists to remove duplicates using Map

Tags: rest-api

I have gone through a few posts regd this but I am unable to get a solution I want.I have 2 salesforce instances(say source & destination) and the objective is have a bunch of records in source to be inserted into the destination.

**code for source :**

```
global class InsertMultipleAccountsBatchApex implements Database.Batchable<SObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts
{
 public string jsonList;
 global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
 {
    String obj = '%United Airlines%';
    String query = 'Select Id, Name from Account where Name LIKE :obj';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
 }
 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Account> scope)
 {     
    if(Helper.GetAccessToken() != NULL)
    {
       Http h=new Http();

       HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();

       req.SetMethod('POST');

       req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+Helper.GetAccessToken().access_token);

       req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json; charset=UTF-8');

       req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');

       req.setEndpoint('https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/AccountRest/');

       if (scope.size() > 0)
       {
        jsonList=JSON.Serialize(scope);

        req.setBody(jsonList);

        HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 
       }}}
```

**code in destination:**

```
@RestResource(UrlMapping='/AccountRest/')  
global class RestAccountUsingPost
{
 RestRequest req=RestContext.Request;
 RestResponse res=RestContext.Response;
 List<Account> FinalList=new List<Account>();      
 string req_body=req.RequestBody.ToString();
 List<Account> SourceList;
 Map<String,Account> newAccRecMap=new Map<String,Account>();
 if (req_body != NULL)
 {
  SourceList=(List<Account>)JSON.Deserialize(req_body,List<Account>.class); 
  if (SourceList.size() > 0)
  {
  for(Account a:SourceList)
       {
         newAccRecMap.put(a.Name,a); //removes duplicates from sourceList
       } 

  List<Account> orgList=[select ID,Name from Account where Name IN 
                         :newAccRecMap.KeySet()];
  if(orgList.size() == 0)  // initially there are no duplicates
  {
    Database.Insert(newAccRecMap.values(),false);
  }
  else  //if there are duplicates in destination
  {
        orgList.sort();
        for(Account a:orgList)
        {
          if (newAccRecMap.containskey(a.Name))
             newAccRecMap.remove(a.Name); 
    }

    Database.Insert(newAccRecMap.values(),false);
   }
}
```

The batch apex executes correctly so in destination SourceList has values, but still records are not inserted in destination. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Database.insert call on a collection returns an array of [Database.SaveResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_saveresult) objects that you can loop through and check for errors. Stealing the example from that link:

```
// Create two accounts, one of which is missing a required field
Account[] accts = new List<Account>{
    new Account(Name='Account1'),
    new Account()};
Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(accts, false);

// Iterate through each returned result
for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
    if (sr.isSuccess()) {
        // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
        System.debug('Successfully inserted account. Account ID: ' + sr.getId());
    }
    else {
        // Operation failed, so get all errors                
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('Account fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
        }
    }
}
```

Adding logic of this kind to your code code may reveal e.g. a validation error at the destination end that is blocking the insert other than the duplicate name you are working to eliminate.

One likely error is that you are specifying an `Id` (from the source system) when you do the insert (in the destination system). Suggest you set that field to null at the source or destination end.

Comment: I have updated my code to incorporate Database.SaveResult(). Also I removed ID field from source and destination query but it doesnt work, so I copied Map values into a List and ran a loop and it worked. But is there a technique to remove the Keys from Map and keep only the values, in my case I guess I do not require keys while inserting records, because the sourceList comes from a different system. Also I saw a few posts where they say that if the heap size of Map is large then its an issue , so I guess I would want to eliminate the keys and retain values in Map. I hope I am clear.

Comment: @DivyaManohar Generally the keys are small e.g. an Id or Name and the values are large e.g. the whole SObject that can have very many fields. Just taking the `values` of a map at the time of insert is a common pattern and doing anything else is unnecessary.